# Are email headers different when email is in spam?

Tags: email, spam

A bit of a particular question here

Let's say:

- Jane emails Bill and **her email ends up in spam**
- Then Jane emails Jebediah and **her email does NOT end up in spam**.

Assuming nothing changed in email setup and Jebediah got Jane's email because Jane was in his contacts:

*Will the email headers in both instances look the same?*

Our sysadmin team insists that they need emails from within the spam folder, but wouldn't they be identical in both cases if nothing changed on Jane's side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is highly *installation specific*, some filtering packages do inject diagnostic headers into the email that indicates why the message was classified a particular way. These can be useful in identifying faults in delivery.

Google and Hotmail do this fairly reliably, though other services have different behaviour.

Remember, even if an email message was sent with identical headers to two different people the way the message was received can be dramatically different. The SMTP processing pipeline can be quite complicated and a number of processes can tap in, insert, remove, or otherwise manipulate headers before it ends up in the inbox.

Comment: oh wow, so I guess they were right.. i was under the impression that they would be 100% identical. The sending receiving parties are both powered by G Suite (Google workspace) btw.

Comment: There's a 0% chance the headers are perfectly identical. They always differ in at least some tiny way, like the `Received:` headers in particular.

Comment: yep I meant the most relevant info related to DKIM, SPF and DMARC pass/fails

Comment: If Bill had at some point marked Jane as "spam" even on accident, then she could be banned from Bill's email box.  Or, perhaps the content was simply spammy in the way it was written - did she claim to be a Nigerian princess? :)

Comment: Each can can produce different results. Sometimes you have an inconsistency in your DNS. In other cases user behaviour factors in.

Answer (score 1):

The headers might be very similar.  There are some tricks that legitimate business can use to verify their ownership of the domain ([DKIM](https://postmarkapp.com/guides/dkim)) and providence of the email itself ([spf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)).

In the absence of these tools, systems use text-based filters to determine "spammyness".  Some big email handlers (think Google, Yahoo, etc) have a large body of spam and have gotten quite good at just looking at the content to determine spammyness.

Comment: I think you mean "less bad" but yeah. They're still utterly bizarre at times.

Comment: Fair point. I mean, for legitimate Nigerian Princes it's been a nightmare.